# How to use loop in insert's values in php

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to use a loop in insert's Values.

For example

```
$num = count($data);

for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
    echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";

}
 $sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES (    '$data[$c]'   )";
```

If num is 5 then , then column will be created 5. which will be inserted 1 row with 5 columns.

or 
If num is 8 then , then column will be created 8. which will be inserted 1 row with 8 columns.

In **VALUES**, How can i use loop or

Since column number is not fixed. so How to insert column data dynamically which row will be created one(1).

Please any suggestion?

Comment: in your for loop for (...) { if($data[$c] == 5) { // insert query}  }. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I think, THINK after reading the question 4-5 times that he wants dynamic fields in his query, not to run the same query multiple times.

Comment: Can you explain the part of the "dynamic" columns? How can the same table have different number of columns?

Comment: Tanks a lot  Tivie. Every table column is fixed but table is dynamic.This script is for dynamic table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES ( ";
for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
    $sql .= "'" . $data[$c] . "',";

}
$sql = substr($sql,0,-1); // removes last comma
$sql .= ")";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you help me to increase my reputation

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
foreach ($data as &$piece){
  $piece = "('{$piece}')" ; //Or you can specify anything else
}

$values = implode(", ", $data) ;

$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES {$values} ; ";
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to define 2 array of fields list for the two queries

```
$col5 = array('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5');
$col8 = array('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5', 'field6', 'field7', 'field8');
```

then

```
$num = count($data);

for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
    echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";

}

if ($num == 5) {
    $fields = explode($col5, ",");
} else { //assume its 8 if not 5
    $fields = explode($col8, ",");
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (" . $fields . ") VALUES ('" . explode($data, "','") . "')";
```